# Can´t reassign declared variables with Python/Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongodb

I´m creating a login system with Python, Django and Mongo. This is my function

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from pymongo import MongoClient
import bcrypt


def login( req ):
    #hashed = bcrypt.hashpw( p.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt() )
    response = { 'error': 'WTF Error' }

    if req.POST['username'] and req.POST['password']:
        u = req.POST['username']
        p = req.POST['password']
        client = MongoClient()
        result = client['db']['users'].find({'name': u})

        if result:
            for res in result:
                if bcrypt.checkpw( p, res['password'] ):
                    response = { 'error': 'welcome!' }
                else:
                    response = { 'error': 'Invalid password' }
                break   
        else:
            response = { 'error': 'Nobody with that name' }
    else:
        response = { 'error': 'Empty user or password' }


    return render( req, 'crawler/login.html', response )
```

Everytime 'WTF Error' is returned to the template, it´s looks like if statement are ignored

What´s wrong with my code?
I´m newbie with Python

EDIT:

This is a screenshot
[image]

Comment: There are no paths through that code that don't reassign response. Are you sure you have copied the indentation correctly?

Comment: Write a print statement after each variable, if branch, and loop. Run your function and watch all the prints. You will see where the code goes and what each variable is.

Comment: I can see the variables on the console, but 'response' is not changing

Comment: Putting Django aside, this worked perfectly for me. I don't see any problem unless some indentation while writing the code. Turning on tracing or adding print statements will help to debug.

Comment: I printed response on each if or else statement and only the first one works {'error': 'WTF error'} No more prints! But if I print for example u or p variables it works

Comment: You almost certainly have different indentation in your real code. My guess would be that the second `else` actually lines up with the `for`, which means that response is not reassigned if `result` is empty.

Comment: I added an image, I´m using SublimeText3

Comment: The possible other scenario I can think of is, by removing any .pyc files if they are present and rerun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact a single path through this code that does not reassign `response`, and that is the case where the first if statement is true, but the Mongodb query returns an empty set. This is because the result of calling `find()` is a Cursor instance, which is always boolean True, but when iterating it has no contents so skips the for loop.

In your case you seem to only want one result anyway, as you always break after the first iteration. In which case you should use `find_one()` to return a single document and remove the for loop entirely.

```
result = client['db']['users'].find_one({'name': u})
if result:
    if bcrypt.checkpw( p, res['password'] ):
       ...
```